# super cosx legendre series

Tags: calculus

I found this series could you give a explanation it converge very fast for $$-1<x<1$$
$$\cos (x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{I_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(1) \left(2^{n-\frac{1}{2}} \left((-1)^n+1\right) e^{\frac{i \pi  n}{2}} x^n \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1-n}{2},-\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2}-n;-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)}{\Gamma (n+1)}$$
sorry for the english

Comment: Found where? $ $ $ $

Comment: As with your other questions like this, it might be helpful to tell us where you got this from.

Comment: Are all the various special functions in the numerator really appreciably easier to compute than the cosine itself? Also at least some of it seems to be designed to obfuscate -- what's up with $((-1)^n+1)e^{i\pi n/2}$ (which works out to "zero for odd $n$, otherwise $2(-1)^{n/2}$), for example?